# Rails Sign in using devise to authenticate from two db tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, apartment-gem

I have 2 database tables namely `coreteam` and `user`. Both the models are configured with devise.
For now to sign in for core team my API is: `localhost:3000/api/v1/core_teams/sign_in` with following request data.

```
{ 
  "core_team": {
    "email": "ba+admin@gmail.com",
    "password": "Password21"
  }
}
```

And the API for users to sign in is: `localhost:3000//api/v1/users/sign_in`
with the following request data.

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "ba+user@gmail.com",
    "password": "Password20"
  }
}
```

And following is my routes.rb file

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

 root to: 'users#index'

scope 'api/v1', defaults: { format: :json } do
 devise_for :core_teams, controllers: {
   sessions: 'api/v1/sessions',
   passwords: 'api/v1/passwords'
  }

 devise_for :users, controllers: {
   sessions: 'api/v1/sessions',
   invitations: 'api/v1/invitations',
   passwords: 'api/v1/passwords',
   registrations: 'api/v1/registrations'
  }
  end
end
```

And I am using devise sessionscontroller to login. Only difference is the way I am rendering the data.

My sessions_controller.rb is as follows:

```
module Api
 module V1
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   private

    def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
      render json: resource
    end

    def respond_to_on_destroy
      head :no_content
    end

   end
  end
 end
```

Now my aim is to have only one API call to sign in using the same type of requests data. Reason to have two different user table is my app is kind of multi-tenanted and core team is outside of tenant and users are inside tenant.

[image: CoreTeam and Tenant Architecture]

Comment: I think if you monkey patch where `resource` is being set, by setting it either to an admin or user would be your best bet. You could have the client FE submit the type along with the id to conditionally set the resource

Comment: I would really just setup a single user class and roles. I never get why people make a huge mess on the authentication layer when what they are trying to solve is authorization.

Comment: The reason for having ways for user login is due to such architecture. User is under Tenant (Using apartment gem) and CoreTeam is outside the Tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

routes

```
post "/api/v1/sign_in" => "api/v1/sessions#create"

devise_for :users, ...
devise_for :core_teams, ...
```

api/v1/sessions_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
      before_action :rewrite_request_params, only: %i[create]

    protected
      def devise_mapping
        @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[account_name || :user]
      end

    private
      def rewrite_request_params
        return unless account_name
        request.params[account_name] = {
          email: params[:email],
          password: params[:password],
        }
      end

      def account_name
        @account_name ||= account.class.name.underscore.to_sym if account
      end

      def account
        return if params[:email].blank?
        return @account if defined? @account
        @account = CoreTeam.find_by(email: params[:email]) || User.find_by(email: params[:email])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this will allow you to submit params to `/api/v1/sign_in` for both `User` and `CoreTeam`

First it will look for an `account` in `core_teams` table then `users` table. if found it will rewrite the `request.params`

```
# core_teams
$.post('/api/v1/sign_in', {
  "email": "ba+admin@gmail.com",
  "password": "Password21"
})

# users
$.post('/api/v1/sign_in', {
  "email": "ba+user@gmail.com",
  "password": "Password20"
})
```